# Thread safety with Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, concurrency

Hi I was wondering about thread safety in spring boot applications.

I have configured JMS listener that reads messages concurrently and then I call a mapper to convert the request into a desirable format and then send message.

So, Coming to mapper now that I am listening messages concurrently do I need to ensure thread safety in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application servers use several concepts to make multithreading easy for the average programmer.

The most important concept is thead confinement. To understand the concept, read the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6261910/11934850).

In your situation, there is more than one thread involved, but there is also some API that enables you to handle data from one thread to the other in a safe way. Most of the time there are thread pools envolved, see [Introduction to Thread Pools in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/thread-pool-java-and-guava).

In JMS there are some objects that are not allowed to be used in different threads (e.g. the Session object), some are (e.g. the Connection, the JmsTemplate). Read the answers to ["Why JMS Session Object is not thread safe?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20560817/11934850). The consequences are listed [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19340-01/820-6767/aeqdb/index.html).

I recommend reading the [Spring documentation on this topic](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#jms).